# How to change time in appointments in Calendar to 12 hour format?

Tags: time, calendar, format-conversion

The calendar appointment format in Ubuntu is 24 hour.  How do you change it to a 12 hour format?  I have my clock set for 12 hour, but there is no option in the Calendar to switch formats.  Can it be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple; Go to System settings --> date & Time --> [Clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adGWl.png) 

 Then you can select the favorite Time Format

Comment: That doesn't change the appointment time setup.  I have that area set to 12 hours not 24, but the appointment time is in 24 hour format.